# Trying to understand underscore.js source - call and apply used in library

Tags: javascript, call, underscore.js, apply

In Jeremy Ashkenas's awesome Underscore.js library, I tried to understand one thing about the source file. I do not understand this:

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

So that:

```
args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2);
```

`.call` or `.apply` are the methods of the functions. But here, which functions do `.call` refer to? The first parameter should be the context, but `arguments` is context? The second parameter should be the params to pass in the functions. Here they are number `2`. What does this mean? Sometimes in the library, it uses `1` or `0`. Are they the number of the params to pass in the functions?

```
_.bind = function bind(func, context) {
    var bound, args;
    if (func.bind === nativeBind && nativeBind) return nativeBind.apply(func, slice.call(arguments, 1));
    if (!_.isFunction(func)) throw new TypeError;
    args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return bound = function() {
      if (!(this instanceof bound)) return func.apply(context, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
      ctor.prototype = func.prototype;
      var self = new ctor;
      var result = func.apply(self, args.concat(slice.call(arguments)));
      if (Object(result) === result) return result;
      return self;
    };
  };
```

Question 2: 
I do not quite understand the logic of this function. Need help to understand. An example should be very helpful.

```
  // Invoke a method (with arguments) on every item in a collection.
  _.invoke = function(obj, method) {
    var args = slice.call(arguments, 2);
    return _.map(obj, function(value) {
      return (method.call ? method || value : value[method]).apply(value, args);
    });
  };
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 7):

The "slice" function on the Array prototype expects that `this` will refer to the array on which it's supposed to operate.  In other words, if you have a real array:

```
var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
```

and you call `slice()`:

```
var sliced = myArray.slice(1);
```

Then in that call to `slice()`, `this` refers to the array "myArray". As Raynos notes in a comment:

```
myArray.slice(1)
```

is the same as

```
myArray.slice.call(myArray, 1);
```

Thus when you use `call()` to invoke the function, and pass it `arguments` as the context object, the `slice()` code operates on `arguments`. The other parameters passed via `.call()` are simply the parameter or parameters for `slice()` itself. In my example above, note that I passed 1 to the function.

Now as to your second question, that `.invoke()` function first isolates the arguments passed in after the first two. That means that when you use `_.invoke()` you pass it two *or more* arguments: the first is the list to operate on, the second is the method, and the (optional) subsequent arguments are passed to the method for each element of the list.

That call to `_.map()` is complicated (and in fact I think it's got a little nonsense in it).  What it's doing is iterating over the list, calling a function for each value in the list.  What that function does to first determine whether the "method" parameter really is a function. If it is, then it calls that function via `.apply()` with the element of the list as the context.  If "method" is *not* a function, then it assumes it's the name of a property of each list element, and that the properties are functions.

So for example, with a simple list it's pretty simple:

```
var myList = [1, 2, 3];
var result = _.invoke(myList, function(n) { return this * n; }, 2);
```

That will give the result `[2, 4, 6]` because the function I passed multiplies its context object (`this`) by the parameter passed, and I passed 2 in the call to `_.invoke()`.

With a more complicated list, I can use the second flavor of `_.invoke()` and call a method on each object in the list:

```
var getName = function(prefix) { return prefix + " " + this.name; };
var list = [
  { name: "Bob", getName: getName },
  { name: "Sam", getName: getName },
  { name: "Lou", getName: getName }
];

var result = _.invoke(list, "getName", "Congressman");
```

That will call the "getName" function on each object in the list and return a list made from the results. The effect will be the list `["Congressman Bob", "Congressman Sam", "Congressman Lou"]`.

Now about that nonsense.  In the code for `_.invoke()`:

```
return _.map(obj, function(value) {
  return (method.call ? method || value : value[method]).apply(value, args);
});
```

That subexpresion `method || value` will *always* return the value of "method", or at least almost always barring some exotic trick.  If `method.call` is truthy, then a reference to `method` must also be truthy. Also, if it were my code, I'd inspect `method` *outside* the `_.map()` callback so that the decision doesn't have to be made over and over again. Maybe something like:

```
return _.map(obj, method.call ?
  function(value) { method.apply(value, args); } :
  function(value) { value[method].apply(value, args); }
);
```

Comment: `myArray.slice(1) === slice.call(myArray, 1)`

Comment: @Raynos, it's actually false. `slice` creates two different array objects, which aren't identical.

Comment: @katspaugh I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  Oh wait ... do you mean that two *separate* calls to `slice()` creates two different arrays?  Well yes that's true of course, but I don't think that's what Raynos meant (despite the use of `===`) He meant that it has the same net effect.

Comment: Then he probably shouldn't have used *code* to express the informal equality.

Comment: @katspaugh your not supposed to take it literally. It's a context dependent statement, it's not code, the `===` means the statements have the same effect

Comment: @Pointy Your demo and explanation are straight forward and easy to understand. Thank you very much for your help. I fully understand the call(), apply(), _.invoke() now. One thing I want to say that underscore.js rocks, I will definitely want to use it in most of the cases in my JS development workflow along with jQuery, etc. Trying to write my own code instead of finding or using other jquery plugins. In the underscore.js version 1.3, Jeremy updated the condition to    (_.isFunction(method) ? method || value : value[method]).apply(value, args);